# What's the point of the ajax success handler?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to understand ajax....

In my ajax call I have a success handler. I also have a target url that ajax is throwing the data to (best way I can think of describing it).

- If my target url is valid - success.
- If my target url is misspelt - success.
- If my target url is garbage - success.

So... what purpose does it serve?

```
// 1. Put a trigger on the right button 
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
    alert("trigger event");

// 2. serialise the form data
    var formData = $("#myForm").serializeArray();

// 3. make an ajax call to the controller

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controllerThatDoesntExist/function",
        data: formData,
        success: successHandler,
        dataType: "text"
        });

});

function successHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        alert("Success is 100% guaranteed");  
    };
```

Comment: A function to be called if the request succeeds. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You last two points won't work at all if that is the case, can you produce a test case? If there are these cases then error callback should be used to see the error cause.

Comment: @Suraj - So because the request succeeds 100% of the time, the function always gets called...  seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @Maxcot http://jsfiddle.net/KT5Ge/ check this fiddle.

Comment: @Maxcot Nope its not pointless it gives you a logic if your call succeeds you can write further functions or if it fails you can handle it on error function.

Comment: Thanks guys... I don't disagree that it should work as you have stated. And the jsfiddle certainly proves it. I think I've just had enough of ajax for today.

Answer (score 3):

If you're seeing the `success` function get called for resources that don't exist, it means that the server the resources are being loaded from is sending an invalid response that uses HTTP status code 200 rather than one of the 4xx series. The problem is the server, not jQuery's `ajax` function.

If the server does what it's supposed to do with invalid URLs, `ajax` won't call `success` and will call `error` instead (and similar functions in the new `Promise` stuff).

Here's a successful request: http://jsfiddle.net/5F7NV/

```
// Successful request
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/",
    success: function(html) {
        console.log("Success, got back " + html.length + " characters of HTML");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR) {
        console.log("Error, status code: " + jqXHR.status);
    }
});
```

And here's an unsuccessful request: http://jsfiddle.net/5F7NV/1

```
// Request for something that doesn't exist
$.ajax({
    url: "/blargleflap",
    success: function(html) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR) {
        console.log("Error, status code: " + jqXHR.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm sitting here laughing... I've been exploring ajax the whole day, I'm no closer to understanding how it works, but it does. I've got a codeigniter MVC framework, running on a XAMPP local apache server. I make an ajax call to a url that is totally ficticious, and I get a positive response. every. damn. time.  Time to sleep I think.

Comment: @Maxcot: Because apparently your server is sending back 200 response. Every. Time. (Please don't swear on SO.)

Comment: Sorry... been a long day. What is a 200 response? and how do I change it? OR perhaps, how do I verify that it is configured as such?

Comment: @Suraj - which part? The code I posted is the actual code from my CodeIgniter VIEW.

Comment: @Maxcot: Servers reply to HTTP requests with a status code saying what the high-level of the result was (and any data that the response should have). `404` is one of the most famous codes, it means "not found." `200` is the most common: It means "OK". The `ajax` function looks at the status code to determine whether the call succeeded. So you need to look at why your server is sending back 200 (OK) replies when it should be returning 404s (NOTFOUND). I don't know CodeIgniter, so I can't help you configure it, but that's the fundamental issue.

Comment: OK, I added a couple of lines to my VIEW. If I make an ajax call to a valid URL I get this: `Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [1] => Date...` and if I make an ajax call to an invalid URL I get this: `Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found [1] => Date...`   So it looks like my server is doing the right thing. But the ajax script always succeeds. 100% of the time.

Comment: @Maxcot: There's an error in your testing somewhere. Again, this does work. Here's a successful request: http://jsfiddle.net/5F7NV/ And here's an unsuccessful request: http://jsfiddle.net/5F7NV/1

Comment: Yes, I don't disagree. I'm just stumped as to how to proceed.